# SQL Count Average

Tags: mysql

I have table like

```
id     userid  semid  courseid  coursename  total
1       36      17       13       CA         23
2       36      17       5        CB         46        
3       36      17       8        CC         20
4       36      19       16       CD         34
5       36      19       13       CA         31
6       36      19       3        CA#        29
7       36      19       7        CE         60
8       36      10       9        CK         32
9       36      10       15       CH         56
```

I need average of semid for a userid i.e.,   SUM(courseid) /count (moduleid), It was showing 9 as module count, but I have only 3 modules.
This is my query

```
SELECT userid, SUM(total)/count(semid) FROM custom WHERE userid=36
```

Comment: The 9 is from `count` returning the number of rows, and not counting up the number of unique values for that column (assuming you were running the query on the particular example...otherwise I'm not sure where 9 would be coming from)

Comment: count(semid) is giving you 9 as there are 9 rows for 36, if you need distinct semid, use keyword "distinct"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT userid, SUM(total)/count(distinct semid) FROM custom WHERE userid=36
```

Try this query

Answer (score 2):

just use the `AVG( )` function

```
SELECT   userid, semid, AVG(total)
FROM     custom
WHERE    userid = 36
GROUP BY userid, semid
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4797b/2)

Comment: He is not looking for AVG of total, instead AVERAGE for distinct semId. Your query may result the same wrong response what he has in Question.

Comment: it's because the OP is unclear about his question. he doesn't give the exact information, and all he did was to give only the query he used. how did you understand about the title `Count Average`? :)

Comment: I am clear about my question and sundar answer was working in all ascepts, Why we need to have a discussion

Answer (score 0):

There is MYSQL aggregate function `AVG()` for finding Average . @John Totet Woo has posted the answer.